# 23.2 PROJECT 2 : Data Visualization using LOOPS

Tags: python

This program will display a set of authors and the number of novels written by each author in both a table and a histogram. You will ask the user for all of the information. Using what you learned about incremental development, use the following approach to create your program:

Prompt the user for the information about the table. First, ask for the title of this data set by prompting the user for a title for data. Output the title.

Ex:

```
Enter a title for the data:
Number of Novels Authored
You entered: Number of Novels Authored
```

The table will have two columns; one for the authors and one for the number of novels. Prompt the user for the headers of two columns of the table. Output the column headers.

Ex:

```
Enter the column 1 header:
Author name
You entered: Author name

Enter the column 2 header:
Number of novels
You entered: Number of novels
```

Prompt the user for data points. Data points must be in this format: string, int, representing the author and the number of novels written by the author. Store the information before the comma into a string variable and the information after the comma into an integer. The user will enter -1 when they have finished entering data points. Output the data points. Store the string components of the data points in a list of strings. Store the integer components of the data points in a list of integers.

Ex:

```
Enter a data point (-1 to stop input):
Jane Austen, 6
Author: Jane Austen
Number of Novel(s): 6
```

Perform error checking for the data point entries as follows:
If entry has no comma and is not -1
Output: Error: No comma in string.

If the error occurs, output the appropriate error message and prompt again for a valid data point. You can assume that if a comma is present, then the data point is entered correctly.

Ex:

```
Enter a data point (-1 to stop input):
Ernest Hemingway 9
Error: No comma in string.

Enter a data point (-1 to stop input):
Ernest Hemingway, 9
Author: Ernest Hemingway
Number of Novel(s): 9
```

Output the information in a formatted table. The title is right justified with a minimum field width value of 33. Column 1 has a minimum field width value of 20. Column 2 has a minimum field width value of 23.

```
Ex:
        Number of Novels Authored
Author name         |       Number of novels
--------------------------------------------
Jane Austen         |                      6
Charles Dickens     |                     20
Ernest Hemingway    |                      9
Jack Kerouac        |                     22
F. Scott Fitzgerald |                      8
Mary Shelley        |                      7
Charlotte Bronte    |                      5
Mark Twain          |                     11
Agatha Christie     |                     73
Ian Flemming        |                     14
J.K. Rowling        |                     14
Stephen King        |                     54
Oscar Wilde         |                      1
```

Output the information as a formatted histogram. Each name is right justified with a minimum field width value of 20.

Ex:

```
         Jane Austen ******
     Charles Dickens ********************
    Ernest Hemingway *********
        Jack Kerouac **********************
 F. Scott Fitzgerald ********
        Mary Shelley *******
    Charlotte Bronte *****
          Mark Twain ***********
     Agatha Christie *************************************************************************
        Ian Flemming **************
        J.K. Rowling **************
        Stephen King ******************************************************
         Oscar Wilde *
```

For this project, you can assume that the user will not enter duplicate author names.

```
title = input("Enter a title for the data:\n")

print('You entered:',title)

column1 = input("\nEnter the column 1 header:\n")

print('You entered:',column1)

column2 = input("\nEnter the column 2 header:\n")

print('You entered:',column2)

while True:
    datapoint = input("\nEnter a data point (-1 to stop input):\n")
    if datapoint == '-1':
        break


while datapoint != '-1':
    if datapoint == '-1':
        break
    my_dict = {}
    if ',' not in datapoint:

        print('Error: No comma in string.\n')
        datapoint = input("Enter a data point (-1 to stop input):\n")
    else:

        split = datapoint.split(',')
        first = split[0].strip()
        second = split[1].strip()

        my_dict[first] = second

        print("Data string:",first)
        print("Data integer:",second)
        break
```

This is what I have so far and it only satisfies a 20/100.

Comment: It's unclear what help you actually want (short of someone finishing your homework for you). Have you got a specific problem you need help with?

Comment: A heads up, soliciting help on StackOverflow for homework problems is usually against School Honor Codes. Posting the question nearly word for word makes it VERY easy to find. Check out this [Github repo](https://github.com/genchang1234/How-to-cheat-in-computer-science-101) for some more information.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code with comments to help you understand it. This will give full points in the lab.

```
# Dictionary we'll be using later on to print our table and histogram
author_dict = {}

# Title for our table later on, lab requires this be the first input though
string = str(input('Enter a title for the data:\n').rstrip())
print('You entered:', string,)
print('')

# First column header for our table, second input
header1 = str(input('Enter the column 1 header:\n').rstrip())
print('You entered:', header1)
print('')

# Second column header for our table, third input
header2 = str(input('Enter the column 2 header:\n').rstrip())
print('You entered:', header2)
print('')

# Loop used to check for mistakes with how the input is formatted
while True:
# The fourth input, for data_point consisting of a name and an int
    data_point = input('Enter a data point (-1 to stop input):\n')

# Since -1 is our exit code, we need to compare to it first
    if data_point == '-1':
        break

# Outputs an error if user did not include a comma in the data point
    elif ',' not in data_point:
        print('Error: No comma in string.')
        print("\n".rstrip("\n"))
    else:
# Outputs an error if user tries to submit more than 2 data points
        if len(data_point.split(',')) > 2:
            print ('Error: Too many commas in input.')
            print("\n".rstrip("\n"))

# Outputs an error if user doesn't include an int in the data points
        else:
            if not(data_point.split()[-1].isnumeric()):
                print('Error: Comma not followed by an integer.')
                print("\n".rstrip("\n"))

# If no errors are found, the data begins to be processed for output
            else:

#Converts the data point string input into a list of substrings,
#then from a list into a string variable for the author and
# an int variable for the number of books
                blist=data_point.split(',') 
                string_num = int(blist[1])
                string_auth = str(blist[0])
# Appends the authors as keys and number of books as values to our 
# dictionary during each iteration of the loop
                author_dict[string_auth] = string_num

# Outputs the author and number of books for this iteration of the loop
                print('Data string:',blist[0], end='\n')
                print('Data integer:',string_num, end='\n')
                print('')
print('')

# Table formatting
format_title = '{title:>33}'
format_table = '{name:<20}{sep:1}{number:>23}'

# Print the table title and headers based on the formatting above
print(format_title.format(title=string))
print(format_table.format(name=header1, sep='|', number=header2))
print('-' * 44)

# Iterates through the dictionary items to fill in the table data
for k, v in author_dict.items():
    print(format_table.format(name=k, sep='|', number=v))
print('')

# Histogram formatting
format_hist = '{names:>20}{space:1}{hist:<1}'

# Iterates through the dictionary items to fill in the histogram
for k, v in author_dict.items():
    hist_string = ''
    for i in range(v):
        hist_string += '*'
    print(format_hist.format(names=k, space=' ', hist=hist_string))
```

Here is the code without my comments. Hope this helps you understand. Zybooks isn't always great at fully explaining concepts to students.

```
author_dict = {}

string = str(input('Enter a title for the data:\n').rstrip())
print('You entered:', string,)
print('')

header1 = str(input('Enter the column 1 header:\n').rstrip())
print('You entered:', header1)
print('')

header2 = str(input('Enter the column 2 header:\n').rstrip())
print('You entered:', header2)
print('')

while True:
    data_point = input('Enter a data point (-1 to stop input):\n')
    if data_point == '-1':
        break
    elif ',' not in data_point:
        print('Error: No comma in string.')
        print("\n".rstrip("\n"))
    else:
        if len(data_point.split(',')) > 2:
            print ('Error: Too many commas in input.')
            print("\n".rstrip("\n"))
        else:
            if not(data_point.split()[-1].isnumeric()):
                print('Error: Comma not followed by an integer.')
                print("\n".rstrip("\n"))
            else:
                blist=data_point.split(',') 
                string_num = int(blist[1])
                string_auth = str(blist[0])
                author_dict[string_auth] = string_num
                print('Data string:',blist[0], end='\n')
                print('Data integer:',string_num, end='\n')
                print('')
print('')

format_title = '{title:>33}'
format_table = '{name:<20}{sep:1}{number:>23}'
print(format_title.format(title=string))
print(format_table.format(name=header1, sep='|', number=header2))
print('-' * 44)
for k, v in author_dict.items():
    print(format_table.format(name=k, sep='|', number=v))
print('')

format_hist = '{names:>20}{space:1}{hist:<1}'
for k, v in author_dict.items():
    hist_string = ''
    for i in range(v):
        hist_string += '*'
    print(format_hist.format(names=k, space=' ', hist=hist_string))
```